# How I add and assign my own URL protocol to a port

Tags: http, url, https, uri, url-scheme

Can someone can show me how I can add my own URL protocol and assign it to a specific port for a browser to resolve my URL?, for example the HTTP:// is assigned to the port 80, so when I enter a website that has http:// the browser will resolve it to the port 80 by default; so I want to create my own protocol, that I want to be like this:

myprotocol:// = Port 8888

myprotocol://website.com -> Browser -> website.com:8888 -> (Browser resolves my protocol to my assignated port)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program binding to your protocol (you can putting a key-value pair to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in windows ) , your program get the url , do some simple string process , changing the url port to 8888 and the protocl to http(s) , and then launch the brower to open the new url , so that your protocol comes true.

Comment: NO, I don't want to launch a program when entering the URL, I want to access a website with my custom protocol

Comment: I mean the URL lauch the program and then  the program will auto launch the website for you in your own rule ,  I think whatever you need to write down some code to make your unique protocol .

Comment: I need step-by-step instructions, I am not an expert in programming.